# Not able to Read csv file in Jyputer notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am new to python. I want to read the below csv file in Jupyter notebook. I am using windows. I am using the below command but nothing is happening.

```
import pandas as pd
z=pd.read_csv(r'C:/Users/saket/Downloads/Pokemon/Pokemon.csv')
```

Comment: What does "nothing is happening" mean? What value does `z` have after running this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below lines should work , make sure that you have installed pandas using `pip install pandas`.

```
    import pandas as pd
    data = pd.read_csv(r'C:/Users/saket/Downloads/Pokemon/Pokemon.csv')
    data.head()
```